# Jquery .append() inputs for forms but they aren't being posted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to dynamically add form fields to a form when the user hits an add button. However, while I'm using jquery's append() function and the inputs are appearing ok, they don't POST when the form submits and I'm stumped. (newbie)

so to explain I have a form:

```
<div class="belt">
    <div class="halfFormWrap left">        
    <form action="/myapp/invoices/add/4" id="InvoiceAddForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>
        <div class="input select"><label for="InvoiceRecurring">Recurring</label>
            <select name="data[Invoice][recurring]" id="InvoiceRecurring">
                <option value="Never">Never</option>
                <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
                <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
                <option value="Half yearly">Half yearly</option>
            <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
            </select></div>    
    </div>
    <div class="halfFormWrap right">
    <div id="divWithItemsTables">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="widecol"><div class="input text required"><label for="Item1Details">Details</label><input name="data[Item][1][details]" maxlength="255" type="text" id="Item1Details" required="required"/></div></td>
                <td><div class="input number required"><label for="Item1Amount">Amount</label><input name="data[Item][1][amount]" step="0.01" type="number" id="Item1Amount" required="required"/></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="addbutton">+ add item</div>
    <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></div>
    </form>   
    </div>     
</div>
```

and using javascript I'm adding new form fields when am addbutton gets clicked.

```
var count = 2;
$(".addbutton").click(function(){
    //$("#divWithItemsTables").append('<table><tr><td class="widecol"><div class="input text required"><label for="Item'+count+'Details">Details</label><input name="data[Item]['+count+'][details]" maxlength="255" type="text" id="Item'+count+'Details" required="required"/></div></td><td><div class="input text"><label for="Item'+count+'Amount">Amount</label><input name="data[Item]['+count+'][amount]" type="text" id="Item'+count+'Amount"/></div></td></tr></table>');
    count++;
});
```

but when I submit the form the new fields I've added aren't coming through in the request. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show the js for posting the form

Comment: Syntax errors at `html` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax errors at `html`

```js
var count = 2;
$(".addbutton").click(function(){
    $("#divWithItemsTables").append('<table><tr><td class="widecol"><div class="input text required"><label for="Item'+count+'Details">Details</label><input name="data[Item]['+count+'][details]" maxlength="255" type="text" id="Item'+count+'Details" required="required"/></div></td><td><div class="input text"><label for="Item'+count+'Amount">Amount</label><input name="data[Item]['+count+'][amount]" type="text" id="Item'+count+'Amount"/></div></td></tr></table>');
    count++;
});

$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).serialize(), $(this).serializeArray());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="belt">
    <div class="halfFormWrap left">        
    <form action="" id="InvoiceAddForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>
        <div class="input select"><label for="InvoiceRecurring">Recurring</label>
            <select name="data[Invoice][recurring]" id="InvoiceRecurring">
                <option value="Never">Never</option>
                <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
                <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
                <option value="Half yearly">Half yearly</option>
            <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
            </select><!-- here </div>    -->
    </div>
    <div class="halfFormWrap right">
    <div id="divWithItemsTables">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="widecol"><div class="input text required"><label for="Item1Details">Details</label><input name="data[Item][1][details]" maxlength="255" type="text" id="Item1Details" required="required"/></div></td>
                <td><div class="input number required"><label for="Item1Amount">Amount</label><input name="data[Item][1][amount]" step="0.01" type="number" id="Item1Amount" required="required"/></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
      </div>
    <div class="addbutton">+ add item</div>
    <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></div>
    </form>      
  <!-- here </div>    -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your html. Remove the extera closed `div`(`</div>`).

```
<div class="belt">
    <div class="halfFormWrap left">        
    <form action="/myapp/invoices/add/4" id="InvoiceAddForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>
        <div class="input select"><label for="InvoiceRecurring">Recurring</label>
            <select name="data[Invoice][recurring]" id="InvoiceRecurring">
                <option value="Never">Never</option>
                <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
                <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
                <option value="Half yearly">Half yearly</option>
            <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
            </select>
      </div>    
    <!-- Remove this -->
    <!-- </div> -->
    <div class="halfFormWrap right">
    <div id="divWithItemsTables">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="widecol"><div class="input text required"><label for="Item1Details">Details</label><input name="data[Item][1][details]" maxlength="255" type="text" id="Item1Details" required="required"/></div></td>
                <td><div class="input number required"><label for="Item1Amount">Amount</label><input name="data[Item][1][amount]" step="0.01" type="number" id="Item1Amount" required="required"/></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="addbutton">+ add item</div>
    <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></div>
    </form>   
    </div>     
</div>
```